# Should the Info Box Link to the Active Sorted Sandbox?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, sandbox

The link to the sandbox in the info box is nice, but I was wondering if it might be better to link to change the target of the link from

```
https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges
```

to

```
https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active
```

which would cause the sandbox posts to be sorted by activity as is usually considered the most useful way to browse the sandbox.

#### Some Pros/Cons That Have Been Thought Of

Pros

- Active is the more useful view of the sandbox
- For new users following the info box link, more recently active sandbox posts will tend to serve as better examples of sandbox posts than ones that have had the time to accrue a huge amount of votes.

Cons

- Forcing the sorting in this mostly invisible manner might be confusing for some users.
- The change in sorting will also apply to any meta questions subsequently opened. (from [FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31625))

Answer (score 1):

This is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as of [this update](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22161/66833)