# An update to our info box

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

**EDIT** This is now <s>[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)</s> <s>[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)</s> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)! Thanks to SE for making this happen pretty quickly :)

In case anyone hasn't noticed, we have an info box in the top right corner above the official blog, meta features, and hot meta posts box. This isn't on every site and apparently isn't an easy setting to change and likely requires devs to edit it. As such, I have been instructed to post it for [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) so it goes on the to-do list and hopefully is edited ASAP.

The new text we would like is:

> [Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange) This is a site for recreational programming competitions, not general programming questions. Challenges must have [an objective scoring criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria), and it is highly recommended to first post proposed challenges in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active).

```
<a href="https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange">Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange!</a> This is a site for recreational programming competitions, not general programming questions. Challenges must have <a href="https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria">an objective scoring criterion</a>, and it is highly recommended to first post proposed challenges in the <a href="https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active">Sandbox</a>.
```

(Thanks to caird coinheringaahing for this proposal, [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20883)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done. Reply here if I messed it up.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 11):

## Link to the active-sorted sandbox

Answer (score -4):

## Link to the sandbox normally (keeps the user's client-side sorting method)